# Are there any known limitations with Windows Forms button scriptblocks?

Tags: azure, powershell, winforms, microsoft-teams, azure-powershell

I would like to build a Windows Forms application that uses the MicrosoftTeams module in the background and performs bulk actions.

To start with, a connection to Azure must always be established. For this I want to use the integrated Windows authentication.

For example, in the PowerShell Console I simply execute the following line to establish a connection:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccountId ' user@contoso.com'
```

Now I wanted to execute this scriptsnipped when a button is clicked.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DImport-Module -Name  MicrosoftTeams
$window = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$window.Width = 200
$window.Height = 200
 
$windowButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$windowButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$windowButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$windowButton.Text = "connect teams"
$windowButton.Add_Click({
    write-host 'connecting'
    Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccountId 'user@contoso.com'
    Write-Host 'connected'
})
 
$window.Controls.Add($windowButton)
 
[void]$window.ShowDialog()
```

However, the command cannot be executed correctly. PowerShell simply hangs on the command. There is no error message and no timeout.

Do you have any idea what the problem could be? Are these limitations of Windows Forms and if so, how can I work around them?

Edit:
I think my question was not formulated precisely enough. But it is very difficult for me to describe the problem. So I will share some additional codes/logs in hope that this will avoid misunderstanding.

If I change the authentication method from this:

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccountId 'user@contoso.com'
```

to this

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

the code works fine (also in the script block for the Windows form event button). Unfortunately, the user is then prompted to enter their username and password. I would like to avoid this at all costs.

So my guess is that the code inside the Windows Forms Button Event script block is not accessing the integrated Windows authentication.

To investigate the issue, I enabled the event logging feature for this cmdlet.

First, the log of the stuck cmdlet (within a Windows Forms Button Event script block).

```
2022-12-26T10:22:17.5531799Z,Info      ,Logger.Initialize                       ,
Logging initialized at level: Verbose
2022-12-26T10:22:17.5531799Z,Info      ,Logger.Initialize                       ,
Logged in at: DEVPCName
2022-12-26T10:22:17.5531799Z,Info      ,LogAssemblyInfo                         ,
Running assembly         assemblyInfo : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  assemblyLocation : C:\Users\lukas\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\4.9.1\net472\Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect.dll              assemblyName : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   assemblyVersion : 1.2.5.0         fileVersion : 1.2.5.0              productVersion : 1.2.5
2022-12-26T10:22:17.5531799Z,Info      ,Connect-MicrosoftTeams.BeginProcessing  ,
Connecting to the AzureCloud environment.
2022-12-26T10:22:17.5790454Z,Info      ,Connect-MicrosoftTeams.ProcessRecord    ,
Connect to MicrosoftTeams with UserCredential.
2022-12-26T10:22:17.5790454Z,Info      ,Connect-MicrosoftTeams.ProcessRecord    ,
Azure account type: IntegratedWindows
```

The log of a normal execution of the same cmdlet with the same parameters (outside a Windows Forms button click event script block).

```
2022-12-26T10:21:34.3697523Z,Info      ,Logger.Initialize                       ,
Logging initialized at level: Verbose
2022-12-26T10:21:34.3697523Z,Info      ,Logger.Initialize                       ,
Logged in at: DEVPCName
2022-12-26T10:21:34.3697523Z,Info      ,LogAssemblyInfo                         ,
Running assembly         assemblyInfo : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  assemblyLocation : C:\Users\lukas\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MicrosoftTeams\4.9.1\net472\Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect.dll              assemblyName : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Connect, Version=1.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   assemblyVersion : 1.2.5.0         fileVersion : 1.2.5.0              productVersion : 1.2.5
2022-12-26T10:21:34.3697523Z,Info      ,Connect-MicrosoftTeams.BeginProcessing  ,
Connecting to the AzureCloud environment.
2022-12-26T10:21:34.3697523Z,Info      ,Connect-MicrosoftTeams.ProcessRecord    ,
Connect to MicrosoftTeams with UserCredential.
2022-12-26T10:21:34.3697523Z,Info      ,Connect-MicrosoftTeams.ProcessRecord    ,
Azure account type: IntegratedWindows
2022-12-26T10:21:34.6700461Z,Info      ,                                        ,
Sending request :https://api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com/Teams.InternalSupport/TelemetryRelay 01234567-8901-2345-6789-012345678901 SendAsync C:\a_work\7\s\Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets\generated\custom\Infrastructure\ModuleCustom.cs:79
2022-12-26T10:21:34.6700461Z,Info      ,                                        ,
RequestUri: https://api.interfaces.records.teams.microsoft.com/Teams.InternalSupport/TelemetryRelay  AttachTargetUriHeaderToAutoRestCmdlets C:\a_work\7\s\Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets\generated\custom\Infrastructure\SendAsyncCallback.cs:198
2022-12-26T10:21:34.6700461Z,Info      ,                                        ,
X-MS-Target-Uri: https://admin1e.online.lync.com/  AttachTargetUriHeaderToAutoRestCmdlets C:\a_work\7\s\Microsoft.Teams.ConfigAPI.Cmdlets\generated\custom\Infrastructure\SendAsyncCallback.cs:210
2022-12-26T10:21:35.3499509Z,Info      ,                                        ,
CsInternalPsTelemetry flightEnabledCommands=(Get-CsTeamsEducationConfiguration,Set-CsTeamsEducationConfiguration,Grant-CsTeamsEventsPolicy,Get-CsOnlineTelephoneNumber,Grant-CsConferencingPolicy,Get-CsClientPolicy,Grant-CsHostedVoicemailPolicy,Grant-CsClientPolicy,Grant-CsMobilityPolicy,Get-CsBroadcastMeetingConfiguration,Grant-CsVoiceRoutingPolicy,Get-CsConferencingPolicy,Get-CsMobilityPolicy,Get-CsBroadcastMeetingPolicy,Get-CsCloudMeetingPolicy,Get-CsVoiceRoutingPolicy,Get-CsGraphPolicy,Get-CsExternalUserCommunicationPolicy,Grant-CsBroadcastMeetingPolicy,Get-CsHostedVoicemailPolicy,Get-CsIPPhonePolicy,Get-CsUserServicesPolicy,Get-CsAudioConferencingProvider,Grant-CsExternalUserCommunicationPolicy,Get-CsOAuthConfiguration,Get-CsMeetingConfiguration,Get-CsTenantCatalogApp,Get-CsDefaultCatalogApp,Get-CsGlobalCatalogApp,Set-CsTeamsAppPermissionPolicy,Set-CsTeamsAppSetupPolicy,Get-CsPushNotificationConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsUpgradeStatus,Get-CsTeamsPinnedApp,Get-CsUCPhoneConfiguration,Get-CsImFilterConfiguration,Set-CsPushNotificationConfiguration,Get-CsTenantUpdateTimeWindow,New-CsTeamsAppSetupPolicy,Grant-CsCloudMeetingPolicy,Get-CsTeamsAppPreset,New-CsTeamsAppPermissionPolicy,Set-CsOAuthConfiguration,Grant-CsIPPhonePolicy,Set-CsClientPolicy,Grant-CsGraphPolicy,Set-CsIPPhonePolicy,New-CsTeamsPinnedApp,New-CsDefaultCatalogApp,Set-CsConferencingPolicy,New-CsClientPolicy,Set-CsMeetingConfiguration,Set-CsUCPhoneConfiguration,New-CsConferencingPolicy,Set-CsExternalUserCommunicationPolicy,Remove-CsClientPolicy,New-CsExternalUserCommunicationPolicy,Set-CsMobilityPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsAppPreset,Set-CsBroadcastMeetingConfiguration,Remove-CsConferencingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsPinnedApp,New-CsMobilityPolicy,Remove-CsExternalUserCommunicationPolicy,Set-CsTeamsUpgradeStatus,Remove-CsMobilityPolicy,Remove-CsDefaultCatalogApp,Set-CsDefaultCatalogApp,New-CsGlobalCatalogApp,Remove-CsGlobalCatalogApp,Set-CsGlobalCatalogApp,New-CsTeamsAppPreset,Set-CsTeamsAppPreset,Set-CsTeamsPinnedApp,New-CsTenantCatalogApp,Remove-CsTenantCatalogApp,Set-CsTenantCatalogApp,New-CsTenantUpdateTimeWindow,Remove-CsTenantUpdateTimeWindow,Set-CsTenantUpdateTimeWindow,Invoke-CsUcsRollback,Get-CsMeetingRoom,Enable-CsMeetingRoom,Set-CsMeetingRoom,Disable-CsMeetingRoom,New-CsTeamsComplianceRecordingPairedApplication,New-CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy,Set-CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy,New-CsTeamsEmergencyNumber,New-CsTeamsCallHoldPolicy,Set-CsTeamsCallHoldPolicy,Get-CsTeamsComplianceRecordingApplication,Remove-CsTeamsComplianceRecordingApplication,Get-CsOnlineNumberPortOutOrderPin,Set-CsOnlineNumberPortOutOrderPin,Get-CsOnlineNumberPortInOrder,New-CsOnlineNumberPortInOrder,Test-CsOnlineCarrierPortabilityIn,Test-CsOnlinePortabilityIn,Remove-CsOnlineNumberPortInOrder,Set-CsOnlineNumberPortInOrder,Remove-CsOnlineTelephoneNumber,Get-CsOnlineApplicationInstanceAssociationStatus,Remove-CsOnlineApplicationInstanceAssociation,New-CsOnlineApplicationInstanceAssociation,Get-CsOnlineApplicationInstanceAssociation,Find-CsOnlineApplicationInstance,Find-CsGroup,Remove-CsCallQueue,New-CsCallQueue,Set-CsCallQueue,Get-CsCallQueue,Get-CsAutoAttendantTenantInformation,Get-CsAutoAttendantSupportedTimeZone,Get-CsAutoAttendantSupportedLanguage,Export-CsAutoAttendantHolidays,Import-CsAutoAttendantHolidays,Get-CsAutoAttendantHolidays,Update-CsAutoAttendant,Remove-CsAutoAttendant,Get-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint,Set-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint,Remove-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint,New-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint,Switch-CsOnlineApplicationEndpoint,Get-CsUserPstnSettings,Set-CsUserPstnSettings,Get-CsOnlineDialInConferencingUser,Test-CsVoiceNormalizationRule,Sync-CsOnlineApplicationInstance,Get-CsTenant,Test-CsInboundBlockedNumberPattern,Get-CsOnlineDialInConferencingLanguagesSupported,Set-CsOnlineDialInConferencingUser,Get-CsOnlineDialInConferencingBridge,Set-CsOnlineDialInConferencingBridge,Get-CsOnlineLisPort,Set-CsOnlineLisPort,Remove-CsOnlineLisPort,Set-CsOnlineLisLocation,New-CsOnlineLisLocation,Set-CsOnlineEnhancedEmergencyServiceDisclaimer,New-CsCallingLineIdentity,Set-CsCallingLineIdentity,Get-CsOnlineLisSubnet,Set-CsOnlineLisSubnet,Remove-CsOnlineLisSubnet,Get-CsOnlineLisSwitch,Set-CsOnlineLisSwitch,Remove-CsOnlineLisSwitch,Get-CsOnlineLisWirelessAccessPoint,Set-CsOnlineLisWirelessAccessPoint,Remove-CsOnlineLisWirelessAccessPoint,Get-CsOnlineLisCivicAddress,Set-CsOnlineLisCivicAddress,Remove-CsOnlineLisCivicAddress,Get-CsOnlineLisLocation,Remove-CsOnlineLisLocation,Get-CsOnlineEnhancedEmergencyServiceDisclaimer,New-CsOnlineLisCivicAddress,Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance,Set-CsOnlineVoiceApplicationInstance,Set-CsOnlineVoiceUser,Test-CsEffectiveTenantDialPlan,Get-CsMeetingMigrationStatus,Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy,Grant-CsExternalAccessPolicy,Grant-CsOnlineAudioConferencingRoutingPolicy,Grant-CsOnlineVoicemailPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsAppPermissionPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsAppSetupPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsCallHoldPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsCallingPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsCallParkPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsChannelsPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsComplianceRecordingPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsCortanaPolicy,Set-CsUser,Grant-CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsFeedbackPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsIPPhonePolicy,Grant-CsTeamsMeetingBroadcastPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsMeetingPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsMessagingPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsMobilityPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsShiftsPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsUpdateManagementPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsUpgradePolicy,Grant-CsTeamsVdiPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsVideoInteropServicePolicy,Get-CsOnlineUser,Get-CsOnlineVoiceUser,Get-CsEffectiveTenantDialPlan,New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance,Get-CsOnlineApplicationInstance,Start-CsExMeetingMigration,Grant-CsCallingLineIdentity,Grant-CsDialoutPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsAudioConferencingPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsEmergencyCallRoutingPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsEnhancedEncryptionPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsWorkLoadPolicy,Grant-CsTenantDialPlan,Grant-CsTeamsFilesPolicy,Remove-CsApplicationAccessPolicy,Remove-CsCallingLineIdentity,Remove-CsExternalAccessPolicy,Remove-CsOnlineVoicemailPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsAudioConferencingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsCallHoldPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsCallingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsCallParkPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsChannelsPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsEmergencyCallRoutingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsEnhancedEncryptionPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsIPPhonePolicy,Remove-CsTeamsMeetingBroadcastPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsMeetingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsMessagingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsUpdateManagementPolicy,Remove-CsTenantDialPlan,Remove-CsTeamsComplianceRecordingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsCortanaPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsFeedbackPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsMobilityPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsShiftsPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsVdiPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsWorkLoadPolicy,Remove-CsOnlineAudioConferencingRoutingPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsFilesPolicy,Grant-CsTeamsSurvivableBranchAppliancePolicy,Remove-CsTeamsSurvivableBranchAppliancePolicy,Remove-CsTeamsAppPermissionPolicy,Remove-CsTeamsAppSetupPolicy,Set-CsOnlineDialinConferencingUserDefaultNumber,Get-CsOnlineDialInConferencingServiceNumber,Set-CsOnlineDialInConferencingServiceNumber,Get-CsDialPlan,Get-CsExternalAccessPolicy,Get-CsOnlineDialInConferencingTenantSettings,Get-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,Get-CsPrivacyConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsAudioConferencingPolicy,Get-CsTeamsCallingPolicy,Get-CsTeamsCallParkPolicy,Get-CsTeamsChannelsPolicy,Get-CsTeamsClientConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsCortanaPolicy,Get-CsTeamsEducationAssignmentsAppPolicy,Get-CsTeamsFeedbackPolicy,Get-CsTeamsGuestCallingConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsGuestMeetingConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsGuestMessagingConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsIPPhonePolicy,Get-CsTeamsMeetingBroadcastPolicy,Get-CsTeamsMeetingConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsMigrationConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsMobilityPolicy,Get-CsTeamsNotificationAndFeedsPolicy,Get-CsTeamsShiftsAppPolicy,Get-CsTeamsShiftsPolicy,Get-CsTeamsTargetingPolicy,Get-CsTeamsUpgradeConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsVdiPolicy,Get-CsTeamsWorkLoadPolicy,Get-CsTenantMigrationConfiguration,Get-CsTeamsFilesPolicy,New-CsExternalAccessPolicy,New-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy,New-CsTeamsAudioConferencingPolicy,New-CsTeamsCallingPolicy,New-CsTeamsCallParkPolicy,New-CsTeamsChannelsPolicy,New-CsTeamsCortanaPolicy,New-CsTeamsFeedbackPolicy,New-CsTeamsIPPhonePolicy,New-CsTeamsMeetingBroadcastPolicy,New-CsTeamsMobilityP...
2022-12-26T10:21:35.3499509Z,Info      ,Connect-MicrosoftTeams.ProcessRecord    ,
Session created with. Account: user@contoso.com, Environment: AzureCloud, Tenant: 01234567-8901-2345-6789-012345678901, domainName: contoso.onmicrosoft.com, AccountType: IntegratedWindows.
```

So now my more specific question is: Is this phenomenon known to anyone or is this a known limitation of Windows Forms? Or is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: You need to execute your event on a different thread because your main thread is being consumed by your `Form`, this is why when you try to run your event the form freezes

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for your answer.
My problem is not the freezing of the window, but that the function 'Connect-MicrosoftTeams' is not executed when it is called by a button.

Comment: What did you mean by "PowerShell simply hangs on the command" ?

Comment: The 'Connect-MicrosoftTeams' command is normally executed within 10 seconds. If the command is executed via the script block after the button click event, the command hangs forever (like a "while($true){}" loop). But it definitely depends on the specific command from the MicrosoftTeams module.

Comment: @Lukas, interesting... Now, this makes me want to experiment with MSTeam to see these particulars. Well, maybe. My org does not use it, so... there's that.

Comment: This `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DImport-Module -Name  MicrosoftTeams` doesn't look good. Looks like you lost some of the Add-Type line and glued `Import-Module` to it where that should be two separate lines.

Comment: @Theo yes, that seems to me to be a copy-paste error. The original code does not have the error.

Comment: @Lukas - Engineering team has raised a bug to investigate on why Connect-MicrosoftTeams hangs when invoked through windows form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function, of course, locate that at the top of your code, and call that in the click event as well.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
# Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DImport-Module -Name  MicrosoftTeams

function ConnectTo-MSTeams
{
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param()

    Write-Host 'connecting'

    Get-Date | 
    Out-Host

    Write-Host 'connected'
}

$window               = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$window.Width         = 200
$window.Height        = 200
$window.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
 
$windowButton          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$windowButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$windowButton.Size     = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$windowButton.Text     = 'connect teams'
$windowButton.Add_Click({ConnectTo-MSTeams})
 
$window.Controls.Add($windowButton)
 
[void]$window.ShowDialog()
# Results
<#
connecting

Monday, December 26, 2022 13:14:01


connected
#>
```

I don't have Teams installed, so, you need to test.

Comment: Your function is running fine. My problem is that the specific function "Connect-MicrosoftTeams" is not running. It seems that the function does not have enough permissions to perform a login for the user.

Comment: As noted, I do not have MS Teams, and cannot evaluate/repro anything dealing with that. Yet, this is just odd. If you are able to run in it the PS shell/ISE/VSCode with your currently logged-on credentials (whatever user privilege level you are using), and pass in that email address, then I'd expect the MSTeams cmdlet to just work, but obviously, it is not. However that is not the control of the function, but an expectation of something dealing with that cmdlet.  Try the approach that 'Santiago Squarzon', says to see if there is a change.